# Guess tags of a paragraph programmatically using python

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I've trying to read about NLP in general and nltk in specific to use with python. I don't know for sure if what am looking for exists out there, or if I perhaps need to develop it.

I have a program that collect text from different files, the text is extremely random and talks about different things. Each file contains a paragraph or 3 maximum, my program opens the files and store them into a table.

My question is, can i guess tags of what the paragraph is about? if anyone knows of an existing technology or approach, I would really appreciate it.

Thanks,

Comment: Since tags tend to be nouns, if you could locate all the nouns in the paragraph and count them up that might be a naive solution. The problem is if the two paragraphs are about lions and tigers you'd probably want a 'cats' label. If that's what you're looking for then you'll need to use a dictionary of associations and cross check those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your task is called "document classification", and the [nltk book](https://sites.google.com/site/naturallanguagetoolkit/book) has a whole chapter on it. I'd start with that.

It all depends on your criteria for assigning tags. Are you interested in matching your documents against a pre-existing set of tags, or perhaps in topic extraction (select the N most important words or phrases in the text)?

Answer (score 0):

You should train a classifier, the easiest one to develop (and you don't really need to develop it as NLTK provides one) is the naive baesian. The problem is that you'll need to classify manually a corpus of observations and then have the program guess what tag best fits a given paragraph (needless to say that the bigger the training corpus the more precise will be your classifier, IMHO you can reach a 80-85% of correctness). Take a look at the [docs](http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/book/ch06.html).